# back_insert_iterator

Tags: c++, итераторы

Как можно использовать `std::back_insert_iterator` для `copy_if` из заполненного вектора в пустой вектор?

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
vector<int> src, dst;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) src.push_back(rand());

copy_if(src.begin(),src.end(),back_inserter(dst),[](int x) { return x > 1000; });

for(auto i: dst)
    cout << i << endl;
```

Т.е. просто вместо целевого итератора - `back_inserter(Container)`.

Comment: И в чём польза тогда?

Comment: А какая польза вам нужна? Если вы просто передадите итератор на начало контейнера, в котором не будет достаточно готового места, то что произойдет? :)

Comment: @SemenStepanov, польза в том, что `std::back_insert_iterator` за Вас вызывает `push_back()` внутри себя